# how to make vertical progressbar with divider

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to make vertical progress bar with dividers on it. however , i am unable to do so.
This code works fine for horizontal progress bar but when i want to make it work like vertical progress bar it doesn't work.
[image]

Any help appreciated.

```
   class ProgressDrawable extends Drawable {
private static final int NUM_RECTS = 10;
Paint mPaint = new Paint();

@Override
protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
    invalidateSelf();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    int level = getLevel();
    Rect b = getBounds();
    float height = b.height();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RECTS; i++) {
        float bottom = height * i / NUM_RECTS;
        float top = bottom + 0.9f * height / NUM_RECTS;
        mPaint.setColor((i + 1) * 10000 / NUM_RECTS <= level? 0xff888888 : 0xffbbbbbb);
      //  canvas.drawRect(left, b.top, right, b.bottom, mPaint);

        //canvas.drawRect(left, b.top, right, b.bottom, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(bottom, b.bottom, top, b.top, mPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}
```

}

Comment: so what is the problem with exchanging x <-> y values? you have a working code, so just swap the coordinates, there are only **four** lines to change in `draw` method...

Comment: I have changed it , but it dissapears

Comment: you were to change 4 lines, not to add anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its late , but if someone want looking for it ,you can see here

```
    private static final int NUM_RECTS = 10;
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int level = getLevel();// It will give the level of progress(0 to 10,000)

        Rect b = getBounds();
        float height = b.height();
        float width=b.width();
        float x=40;
        float y=0;
        for (int i =0; i<NUM_RECTS; i++) {


      if((i+1)*10000/NUM_RECTS>level)
            {
                mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }else{
               mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }


         canvas.drawRect(0,height-x,width,height-y, mPaint);
            //canvas.drawCircle(width/2,height-y,30, mPaint);

            x=x+50;
            y=y+50;
        }

      }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onLevelChange(int level) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: How to use this class with progress bar?